# Spring mongo aggregate nested elements null

Tags: spring, mongodb, kotlin, aggregate, spring-webflux

I have 3 collections: attributes, products and product_attributes. I am trying to retrieve product attributes with aggregation with nested attribute and product in it. But product and attribute always null

service method:

```
    fun findById(id: String): Mono<ProductAttribute> {
    val idField = "_id"
    val productId = "productId"
    val attributeId = "attributeId"
    val attributesDb = "attributes"
    val productsDb = "products"
    val attributeName = "attribute"
    val productName = "product"

    fun lookup(from: String, localField: String, name: String) = LookupOperation.newLookup()
        .from(from)
        .localField(localField)
        .foreignField(idField)
        .`as`(name)

    fun match(id: String) = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where(idField).`is`(ObjectId(id)))

    fun unwind(field: String) = Aggregation.unwind(field)

    val aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
        match(id),
        lookup(productsDb, productId, productName),
        unwind(productName),
        lookup(attributesDb, attributeId, attributeName),
        unwind(attributeName)
    ).withOptions(AggregationOptions.builder().allowDiskUse(true).build())

    return operations.aggregate(aggregation, "product_attributes", ProductAttribute::class.java)
        .last()
        .doOnError { throwable -> logger.error("Failed to get productAttribute", throwable) }
}
```

ProductAttribute.kt

```
@Document(collection = "product_attributes")
data class ProductAttribute(
@Id
@JsonProperty("_id")
val id: String? = ObjectId().toHexString(),
@get:Transient @Value("null") val product: Product?,
@get:Transient @Value("null") val attribute: Attribute?,
val attributeId: String,
val productId: String,
val name: String,
val quantity: Int,
val photos: List<String>
)  : Serializable
```

Response:

```
{
"data": {
"productAttributeId": {
  "id": "62a3bff787418b6f837e9150",
  "product": null,
  "attribute": null,
  "name": "string",
  "quantity": 1,
  "photos": [
    "string"
  ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the the `@Value` annotation, is that causing those two fields to always be `null`?

Comment: @MontgomeryWatts I thought about this, but I didn't find s way to start my application without it. I am using reactive Mongo which doesn't have dbref. So I am using entity with product entity and productId to search entity. I don't store product entity in db. Without `@Value("null")` it can't bind param to constructor `No property product found on entity class ProductAttribute to bind constructor parameter to!`

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround I have ended up with this result:

I made aggregate method with generic type. It will aggregate to Any type and then map to my specific type.

```
inline fun <reified T> aggregate(
    aggregation: Aggregation,
    collectionName: String,
    operations: ReactiveMongoOperations,
    objectMapper: ObjectMapper
): Flux<T> =
    operations.aggregate(aggregation, collectionName, Any::class.java)
        .map { data -> objectMapper.convertValue(data, T::class.java) }
```

I think there is a way to implement custom converter. I will think about this later. I will update answer on success